# Merge dictionaries from multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have three list with multiple dictionaries inside.

```
list1 = [{'question': u'Fan offline information can be found on what Screen under General Menu? '}, {'question': u'What is the tool for F5 BIGIP to get packet traces. '}, {'question': u'On a HTTP Health Monitor configuration. If Receive string and Disabling string matched and Reverse is enabled. What would be the status of pool members?'}]
list2 = [{'answer': u'SysteminfoScreen'}, {'answer': u'qkview'}, {'answer': u'Offline'}]
list3 = [{'correct_answer': u'SysteminfoScreen'}, {'correct_answer': u'TCP Dump'}, {'correct_answer': u'Disabled'}]
```

How can I combine this three list as a result similar to this?

```
[{'question': u'What is the tool for F5 BIGIP to get packet traces. ', 'answer': u'qkview', 'correct_answer': u'TCP Dump'}]
```

Another option if above problem is not achievable

```
list1 = ['Fan offline information can be found on what Screen under General Menu? ', 'What is the tool for F5 BIGIP to get packet traces. ', 'On a HTTP Health Monitor configuration. If Receive string and Disabling string matched and Reverse is enabled. What would be the status of pool members?']
list2 = ['SysteminfoScreen', 'qkview', 'Offline']
list3 = ['SysteminfoScreen', 'TCP Dump', 'Disabled']
```

Merging the three into the same result of:

```
[{'question': u'What is the tool for F5 BIGIP to get packet traces. ', 'answer': u'qkview', 'correct_answer': u'TCP Dump'}]
```

PS

I am using python 2.7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` the dictionary items in the lists. Transform the dictionaries into a list of key-value `tuples`, merge the lists using `+`, then transform the merged list back into a dictionary:

```
[dict(i.items()+j.items()+k.items()) for i, j, k in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
```

In python 3.x, you will need to call `list` on the `dict_items`:

```
[dict(list(i.items())+list(j.items())+list(k.items())) for i,j,k in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
```

Result:

```
[{'answer': 'SysteminfoScreen',
  'question': 'Fan offline information can be found on what Screen under General Menu? ',
  'correct_answer': 'SysteminfoScreen'},
 {'answer': 'qkview',
  'question': 'What is the tool for F5 BIGIP to get packet traces. ',
  'correct_answer': 'TCP Dump'},
 {'answer': 'Offline',
  'question': 'On a HTTP Health Monitor configuration. If Receive string and Disabling string matched and Reverse is enabled. What would be the status of pool members?',
  'correct_answer': 'Disabled'}]
```

Dictionary items are not ordered, so each dictionary may not go in Question-Answer-CorrectAnswer order. Order may be different.

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' is the result of your code, by the way I am using python2

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada This answer is assuming the list-of-dictionaries problem, not the list-of-strings you are trying.

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada This approach uses the list of dictionaries

Comment: @pppery Thanks for noting.

Comment: Oh sorry, yeah my bad. "Dictionary items are not ordered", when you said this you meant the arrangement of the keys right? I got 'correct_answer', 'question', 'answer' on my my end

Comment: This is the best answer and it is only one line. Good Job!

Answer (score 2):

Just loop it, keep it simple and readable:

```
res = []  # keep results

for vals in zip(list1, list2, list3):  # grab each entry 
    d = {}                             # tmp dictionary 
    for subv in vals: d.update(subd)   # update tmp dictionary
    res.append(d)                      # add to result
```

For your input, this yield:

```
[{'answer': 'SysteminfoScreen',
  'correct_answer': 'SysteminfoScreen',
  'question': 'Fan offline information can be found on what Screen under General Menu? '},
 {'answer': 'qkview',
  'correct_answer': 'TCP Dump',
  'question': 'What is the tool for F5 BIGIP to get packet traces. '},
 {'answer': 'Offline',
  'correct_answer': 'Disabled',
  'question': 'On a HTTP Health Monitor configuration. If Receive string and Disabling string matched and Reverse is enabled. What would be the status of pool members?'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following looks pretty nice for the second configuration you offerred. It would need some variable renaming though to be clearer in my opinion.

```
[dict(question=a, answer=b, correct_answer=c) for (a, b, c) in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
```

NOTE:

The above solution could also be written as

```
[{'question': a, 'answer': b, 'correct_answer': c} for (a, b, c) in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
```

but I think my primary answer looks cleaner (less series of braces).

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer as well!